# Flash builder 4.7 slows extremely down after 15 minutes of work

Tags: flash-builder, slowdown

I have a problem with Flash Builder 4.7. 'I can work at the maximum 15 minutes in a normal way. Then it starts slowing down very fast and I'm not able to work with that then.

I'm working in Windows 8 with a computer that has 8 GB RAM, AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 640 processor 3.0GHz.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? I really cannot work like this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

For me, it was just a matter of using the application as an Administrator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a memory issue with FB 4.7 that causes it to become really slow and eventually unusable after some time. I have never had it happen in only 15 minutes, but here are some things you can try:

1) Keep an eye on your FB heap status. Go to Window -> Preferences -> General and check "Show heap status". It shows your current usage out of a total allowed in the bottom right corner of the IDE. If that starts getting high, click the garbage can next to it to try to clear up some memory.

2) Increase your memory settings in your ini file for FB. Go to your FB folder and edit FlashBuilder.ini. Mine has the following lines (this is just some of them, not the entire file). Be sure to restart FB after changing any of these settings.

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

The most important line there is the -Xmx2048m. That means I have given it a max of 2GB of memory to work with. Increasing this number typically allows me to work for longer before it starts to crap out on me.

Comment: worst IDE ever and worst ever language